# If heavy metals bind to sulfur why isn't sulfur used as a safer way to chelate them?

Tags: toxicity, organosulfur-compounds

I was wondering about sulfur as an alternative life-threatening chelators. Why isn't sulfur used as a chelator if heavy metals have an affinity for it?

Comment: 'life-threatening", "safe" - what are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Sulfur-containing molecules are indeed used in chelation therapy: prime examples are [dimercaprol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimercaprol) and [penicillamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penicillamine), both of which contain thiol functional groups.